# how to create my own scoring in GridsearchCV?

Tags: python-3.x, grid-search, scoring

I want to create my own scoring in GridsearchCV, below is my code:
when I run these code, error happens in the last phrase: `grid_x.fit(train_x_pca, x_ref)`. When I using the in-build scoring like 'r2'
`grid_x=GridSearchCV(nnw_model, para_grid, scoring='r2')`, it works.
There should be something wrong in my own scoring def.

```
nnw_model=MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(15,), activation='tanh', \
            solver='lbfgs', learning_rate='adaptive', max_iter=1000,\
            learning_rate_init=0.01, alpha=0.01)  

para_grid=[{'activation': ['tanh', 'logistic', 'relu'], 'hidden_layer_sizes':\
                 [(15,), (17,), (19,), (21,)], 'learning_rate_init':\
                 [0.01,0.001,0.0001]}]


x_ref=ocd_ref['tilt_x']
def Rsq_x_cal(train_x_pca, x_ref):
        nnw_model_x.fit(train_x_pca, x_ref)
        train_x_out=nnw_model_x.predict(train_x_pca)
        metric_x=linregress(train_x_out, x_ref)
        rsq_x=metric_x[2]**2
        return rsq_x
rsq_x_value=make_scorer(Rsq_x_cal, greater_is_better=True)
grid_x=GridSearchCV(nnw_model, para_grid, scoring=rsq_x_value)
grid_x.fit(train_x_pca, x_ref)
```

Answer (score 0):

`scoring` takes a callable with actual outputs and predicted outputs as the parameters and returns a single number.

Something like this:

```
def my_scoring(y_actual, y_predicted):
    score = do_something_on_input()
    return score
```

In your custom method, you are passing the features (`train_x_pca`) and labels (`x_ref`) as input params. Thats the source of error. GridSearchCV will not pass the training data to your method. It will pass already predicted data to it. So your these two lines are unnecessary:

```
    nnw_model_x.fit(train_x_pca, x_ref)
    train_x_out=nnw_model_x.predict(train_x_pca)
    ...
```

Just do this:

```
# Notice that I changed the order of x_ref here from your 
# And deleted those two unwanted lines
def Rsq_x_cal(x_ref, train_x_out):
    metric_x=linregress(train_x_out, x_ref)
    rsq_x=metric_x[2]**2
    return rsq_x
```

Now assuming that `linregress` returns the score between actual and predicted data, the above code should work